# Java, Android passing params to method

Tags: java, android

I'm working through the android developer [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) and we're now creating a method to match to the method name we gave to `android:onClick="sendMessage"`.

Here's the method:

```
/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button
}
```

The text says this about the method:

In order for the system to match this method to the method name given to android:onClick, the signature must be exactly as shown. Specifically, the method must:

- Be public
- Have a void return value
- Have a View as the only parameter (this will be the View that was clicked)

I understand why it must be public and why the return value is void, but why does the method take (View view) instead of just (view)? I'm coming from a Ruby background so the syntax is confusing me. Why do we pass parameters like this?

Comment: if you put only `view`, you would not know the Object type, you always need the Object type of the parameters in a method.

Comment: In Ruby everything is an object and the type of object, aka Class, is implicit. In Java the Object type is explicit so the developer needs to make it clear to the compiler.

Comment: view parameter associated with Object you clicked. If its ImageView, TextView..etc . Type cast them and get the value or set the value . Ex:- ImageView im = (ImageView) view.

Comment: Why you used View parameter in method,use as a string param because you sending the message only

Comment: Thank you all. @Boopathi, I'm following the Android Dev guide, so can't answer that questions given my limited knowledge of Java/Android.

Comment: @settheline could you explain why you use View in the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
why does the method take (View view) instead of just (view)?
```

`View` means it is a `class` and `view` is just a `variable` adding those 2 is making the `view variable` an object of `View class` that can call all of its method.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Lowercase view is like an instance of View? I'll mark as accepted in ten mins.

Comment: @settheline yes it is an instance of View class. +1 this as well thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that `onClick()` method in the `OnClickListener` **Interface** which  requires a parameter of type `View`. When you remove the parameter, Android will still attempt to call method `sendMessage(View view)` but that method does not exist any more, therefore you get error and app will force close.

Parameter **view** is the actual View (Button in your case) that was clicked. With this, you can assign multiple buttons to invoke the same method and inside the method check which button was clicked.

For more information, see this [LINK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html)